# Nullpointer while using response.sendRedirect()

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jboss

I am porting this application from weblogic to Jboss with maven and I am facing this message now on the second page. Any idea of what I could be missing?

It doesn't work with any JSP that I create or in any controller that I call it. I tried to create an instance of the PrintWriter and it outputs the String. The problem is with compiling any jsp through this function. Also, the index.jsp works fine.

Stacktrace in server.log:

```
ESC[0mESC[31m09:51:38,753 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cashvariance].[jsp]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8180-1) JBWEB
000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
        at java.io.PrintWriter.newLine(PrintWriter.java:480) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
        at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:629) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
        at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:740) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ServletWriter.printil(ServletWriter.java:130) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.genPreamblePackage(Generator.java:481) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generatePreamble(Generator.java:584) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3462) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:244) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:359) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:326) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:606) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:308) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cashvariance</groupId>
    <artifactId>cashvariance</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>WebContent</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>cashvariance</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.unboundid/unboundid-ldapsdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>cashvariance</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>pageCheckSeconds</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>keepgenerated</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CashVarianceController</servlet-name>     
        <servlet-class>cashvariance.controller.CashVarianceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DropDownController</servlet-name>     
        <servlet-class>cashvariance.controller.CashVarianceServletForDropDown</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ManageRPAController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cashvariance.controller.ManageRPAServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AddRPAController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cashvariance.controller.AddRPAServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UpdateDeleteController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cashvariance.controller.UpdateDeleteServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DataDumpController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cashvariance.controller.DataDumpServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cashvariance.controller.LoginController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SnoopServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SnoopServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>logon</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>demo.log4j.servlet.LogonServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ForgotPassword</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>demo.log4j.servlet.ForgotPasswordServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>demo.log4j.servlet.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetComments</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>demo.log4j.servlet.GetCommentsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>log4jsetup</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>demo.log4j.servlet.Log4jSetupServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>props</param-name>
            <param-value>log4j.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>watch</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>userDB</param-name>
            <param-value>userDB.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CashVarianceController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CashVarianceController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DropDownController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DropDownController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ManageRPAController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ManageRPAController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AddRPAController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AddRPAController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UpdateDeleteController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/UpdateDeleteController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DataDumpController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DataDumpController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Main</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SnoopServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SnoopServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>logon</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/log4j_demo/logon</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ForgotPassword</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/log4j_demo/ForgotPassword</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/log4j_demo/Register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetComments</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/log4j_demo/GetComments</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/jsp/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
<!--   <welcome-file-list> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
<!--   </welcome-file-list> -->
</web-app>
```

Subsystem for jsp in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <configuration>
                <jsp-configuration development="true" java-encoding="ISO8859_1"/>
            </configuration>
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: Its very difficult without seeing the code. Looking at the stacktrace, there is NullPointerException. Are you calling out.println(null) ?

Comment: @santo the only out.print() in the code is out.print(sdf.format(now.getTime()));, where sdf is a SimpleDateFormater. The file is too long to share. :(

Comment: Here is one link where he faced same issue http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-13194-Erro-ao-Gerar-PDF-iText-Strtus.html.

Comment: To the untrained eye it is the JSP-compiler that fails, not your code.  Are you doing _anything_ that could change the JSP-compiler away from its standard configuration?  Are there any weblogic specific stuff you need to port too?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen There was no specific configuration in the weblogic.xml beside the jsp-descriptor, which I added to the standalone.xml in the jboss server.

Comment: @davis try to set tomcat jasper to provided in your pom, I am pretty sure JBoss already brings its own version of it.

Comment: @beat tried this the error persists :/ Any other idea?

Comment: @davis not sure about the taglibs, could you try setting this to provided too? Also try to remove the JspServlet stuff from the web.xml, i cant see the pageCheckSeconds param here (https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/jasper-howto.html).

Comment: @beat I removed that, set the taglibs to provided and tried to remove the  taglibs, and the error persists.

Comment: Can you post the jsp-configuration part added to the standalone.xml? Maybe some parameters of that configuration are causing the problem (i.e. problems with character encoding).

Comment: @JMSilla  I added to the question.

Comment: Apparently the configuration is OK. Try to remove this configuration, restart JBoss and see if the problem dissapears.

Comment: Didn't work. Curious thing: I am currently using a server of mine with an already running application to test this one. Let's call it TMT and this one that is receiving errors as CV. If I start up the server with only the CV app, it will give me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779930/servlet-service-for-servlet-main-threw-exception-java-lang-error-cant-find/47780618#47780618) error, but if I start up with both at the same time, it will give me the error in this currently thread. Not sure how this could be related.

Comment: I think you pass a mistake format to sdf then it's return value is null. java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Comment: It looks like the system-property `line.separator` isn't set.

Comment: @Edwardth I just set the line.separator to "\n" in standalone.xml and the error persists. Should I set it to something different?

Comment: @davis I don't work with JBoss so i can't tell you where to fix this issue, but the StackTrace clearly indicates that the system-property `line.separator` isn't set or can't retrieved correctly. (Maybe maven creates the problem)

Comment: Provide your jsp and controller code instead of xml files, which are not relevant to your null pointer exception.

Comment: @Edwardth after what you said, I set in standalone.xml the `line.separator` to '\n' and it didn't work. It looks like it gets lost somewhere. But now I've set the property inside the .properties file that I have and it worked! You may want to add that as an aswner below to retrieve the bounty. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work with JBoss so i can't tell you where to fix this issue, but the StackTrace clearly indicates that the system-property line.separator isn't set or can't retrieved correctly.

From the comment of [@davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4048585/davis)

> I've set the property inside the .properties file that I have and it worked!